# Angular route redirects to /# and thus refreshes the page

Tags: angular

I have an angular application that uses the below router.

```
/abc/efg
```

But whenever i click on any of the routers in the html it all gets redirected to the below format.

```
/#
```

and thus refreshes the page. This is affecting all of the routers in the app. The routers are properly defined in the routing module. Can someone help me to resolve these.

Comment: maybe you could show some code?

Comment: try `href="javascript:void(0)"` instead of `href="#"`. will resolve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have some `href="#"` defined in your anchors, replace them with routerLink and the routes you defined in your router module